# Problema con iteracion if

Tags: java, iteraciones

Tengo estas tres clases
ventanaPrincipal.java

```
package com.bruno.javaserialgui.ventanas;
```

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import com.bruno.javaserialgui.*;;

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ventanaPrincipal extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JPanel jpanel;
JFrame ventanaPrincipal;
Dimension d;
ImageIcon im;
public static JTextField numSerial;
JButton bt;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args){
    ventanaPrincipal ventanaPrincipal = new ventanaPrincipal("Java Serial Gui");
}

public ventanaPrincipal(String titulo){
    jpanel = new JPanel();
    jpanel.setLayout(null);
    jpanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

    ventanaPrincipal = new JFrame(titulo);
    d = new Dimension(); //Objeto para obtener el tamaño de la ventana
  //im = new ImageIcon("ruta");
    numSerial = new JTextField();
    numSerial.setBounds(new Rectangle(25, 15, 230, 21));
    numSerial.setText("Ingrese el serial");
    numSerial.setEditable(true);
    numSerial.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);

    bt = new JButton("Comprobar serial");
    bt.setLayout(null);
    bt.setBounds(50, 50, 160, 30);
    bt.addActionListener(this);
    bt.setEnabled(true);

    ventanaPrincipal.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  //ventanaPrincipal.setIconImage(im.getImage()); //Añadimos un icono a la ventan
    ventanaPrincipal.setResizable(true); //Configuramos si se puede redimensionar la ventana
    ventanaPrincipal.setLocation((int) ((d.getWidth()/2)+290), 50); //para ubicar inicialmente donde se muestra la ventana (x,y)
    ventanaPrincipal.setSize(290, 150); //Configurando el tamaño de la ventana
    ventanaPrincipal.setVisible(true);
    ventanaPrincipal.add(jpanel);
    ventanaPrincipal.getContentPane();
    jpanel.add(numSerial, null);
    jpanel.add(bt, null);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == bt){
        comprobarSerial.main();
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
    }

    }
}
```

comprobarSerial.java

```
package com.bruno.javaserialgui;
```

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import com.bruno.javaserialgui.ventanas.*;

public class comprobarSerial{

```
public static void main(){
    String numSerial = ventanaPrincipal.numSerial.getText();

    //A este if no entra el programa

    if(numSerial == "test"){
        System.out.println("hola");
        VentanaAceptado.init();
    }

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/seriales","root","");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                                                    "SELECT usado FROM serial WHERE serial = ?", 
                                                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,  // Esto asegura que el ResultSet pueda ser recorrido en cualquier dirección (adelante o atrás)
                                                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY // Esto asegura que el ResultSet sea de sólo lectura
                                                    );
            ps.setString(1, numSerial);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.beforeFirst(); // Coloca el cursor ANTES de la primera fila del ResultSet
                              // (para esto es que se requiere la opción TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE)


            if(rs.first()){
                if(rs.getInt("usado") == 0){ //0 no usado   1 usado
                    VentanaAceptado.init();
                }else if(rs.getInt("usado") == 1) {
                    VentanaDenegado.init();
                }else{
                    Exception ex = new Exception("Error");
                    throw ex;

                }
            }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
    }
```

}

VentanaAceptado.java

```
package com.bruno.javaserialgui.ventanas;
```

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class VentanaAceptado extends JFrame{
    JPanel jpanel;
    JFrame ventanaAceptado;
    Dimension d;
    JComboBox<String> cb;
    JTextField tf;

public static void init(){
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    VentanaAceptado ventanaAceptado = new VentanaAceptado("Serial aceptado");
}

public VentanaAceptado(String titulo){
    jpanel = new JPanel();
    jpanel.setLayout(null);
    jpanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

    cb.setBounds(HEIGHT, WIDTH, SOMEBITS, HEIGHT);
    cb.addItem("Opcion 1");
    cb.addItem("Opcion 2");
    cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            tf.setText(cb.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    });

    ventanaAceptado = new JFrame(titulo);
    d = new Dimension(); //Objeto para obtener el tamaño de la ventana

    ventanaAceptado.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //ventanaPrincipal.setIconImage(im.getImage()); //Añadimos un icono a la ventan
    ventanaAceptado.setResizable(true); //Configuramos si se puede redimensionar la ventana
    ventanaAceptado.setLocation((int) ((d.getWidth()/2)+290), 50);  //para ubicar inicialmente donde se muestra la ventana (x,y)
    ventanaAceptado.setSize(290, 150); //Configurando el tamaño de la ventana
    ventanaAceptado.setVisible(true);
    ventanaAceptado.add(jpanel);
    ventanaAceptado.getContentPane();
    jpanel.add(cb, null);
}
```

}

Mi problema es que el programa no entra al primer if de la clase comprobarSerial

Cual puede ser el fallo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba cambiando el if de:

```
if(numSerial == "test")
```

por:

```
if(numSerial.equals("test"))
```

El operador `==` en el caso de objetos (como es String) hace una verificación de variables que apunten a un mismo objeto en memoria.

Comment: Que fallo más tonto.